# Error: module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}

Tags: playframework-2.0

I m trying to run Play application which was built by some one else.

I am getting `Error: module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}` when running play command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a `project/build.properties` file if one doesn't exist with the following content:
`sbt.version=0.12.2` resolved the issue.

Comment: looks tricky: `sbt.version=0.13` didn't work and it wasn't apparent that `sbt.version=0.13.0` is required instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the above answer doesn't help you, apparently there seem to be some problem when running the play command in the wrong place in the folder structure. The solution is described here: [org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found on existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896796/org-scala-sbtsbtsbt-version-not-found-on-existing-project)