# org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found on existing project

Tags: playframework, sbt

I've copied a Play framework Scala project from git and when I launch the command $Play, I got this error:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt ${{sbt.version}} ...
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}

    ==== local: tried

      D:\play-2.1.0\repository\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\${{sbt.version}}\ivys\ivy.xml

    ==== Maven2 Local: tried

      file://C:\Users\mghesmoune.stage/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
(see D:\play-2.1.0\framework\.\sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt ${{sbt.version}}
```

I'm using Play-2.1.0, sbt launcher version 0.12.2 (and Windows OS)

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried to run sbt standalone? It might look like sbt is not properly resolved.

Comment: .. Or checked this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327123/error-module-not-found-org-scala-sbtsbtsbt-version

Comment: I had this problem. I had accidentally added `project/` to `.gitingore`. After cloning the `project` directory was omitted, and this error was being thrown.

Answer (score 7):

This can happen if you run the `play` command from a directory that contains an `project` directory with some SBT settings in it.  Try to either remove the `project` directory (but not the one in your app), or move to another directory to run the command.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!  Had an empty project directory in my current directory.

Comment: from james ward - typesafe developer advocate.

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer here: [Error: module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327123/error-module-not-found-org-scala-sbtsbtsbt-version)

Basically, create a project/build.properties file if one doesn't exist with the following content:

```
sbt.version=0.12.2
```