# Why is IDEA not able to resolve sbt.version while running a Play 2.1 project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.1, sbt-0.12

I Have a Play2 project, and wanted to compile in IntelliJ IDEA.

I have `build.properties` correctly read by IntelliJ -- `sbt.version` is 0.12.4.

When I run my project, this happens:

```
/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dsbt.boot.properties=file:////home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true "-Dplay.version= ]; then
  PLAY_VERSION=" -Dsbt.global.base=/tmp/sbt-global-plugin0stub -Dsbt.ivy.home=/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository -Dplay.home=/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -classpath /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar xsbt.boot.Boot "project universail" ~run
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt ${{sbt.version}} ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}

    ==== local: tried

      /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven2 Local: tried

      file:///home/urvoy_p/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt ${{sbt.version}}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's a more detailed log

```html
setting 'ivy.default.settings.dir' to 'jar:file:/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to '/home/urvoy_p/Universail/universail-dev/.idea/modules/.'
setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to 'jar:file:/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VsftpResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.version.PatternVersionMatcher in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.trigger.LogTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntBuildTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IvyRepResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.conflict.RegexpConflictManager in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.updatesite.UpdateSiteResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntCallTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.MirroredURLResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DualResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.JarResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define glob matcher: org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.
setting 'sbt.ivy.home' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository'
setting 'java.runtime.name' to 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment'
setting 'sun.boot.library.path' to '/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/amd64'
setting 'java.vm.version' to '24.75-b04'
setting 'sbt.global.base' to '/tmp/sbt-global-plugin0stub'
setting 'jline.terminal' to 'none'
setting 'java.vm.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'java.vendor.url' to 'http://java.oracle.com/'
setting 'path.separator' to ':'
setting 'java.vm.name' to 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM'
setting 'file.encoding.pkg' to 'sun.io'
setting 'user.country' to 'US'
setting 'sun.java.launcher' to 'SUN_STANDARD'
setting 'sun.os.patch.level' to 'unknown'
setting 'java.vm.specification.name' to 'Java Virtual Machine Specification'
setting 'user.dir' to '/home/urvoy_p/Universail/universail-dev/.idea/modules'
setting 'java.runtime.version' to '1.7.0_75-b13'
setting 'sbt.boot.properties' to 'file:////home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties'
setting 'java.awt.graphicsenv' to 'sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment'
setting 'java.endorsed.dirs' to '/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/endorsed'
setting 'os.arch' to 'amd64'
setting 'java.io.tmpdir' to '/tmp'
setting 'line.separator' to '
'
setting 'java.vm.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'os.name' to 'Linux'
setting 'sbt.log.noformat' to 'true'
setting 'sun.jnu.encoding' to 'UTF-8'
setting 'java.library.path' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/idea-IU-139.659.2/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib'
setting 'java.specification.name' to 'Java Platform API Specification'
setting 'java.class.version' to '51.0'
setting 'play.home' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework'
setting 'sun.management.compiler' to 'HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers'
setting 'os.version' to '3.2.0-75-generic'
setting 'user.home' to '/home/urvoy_p'
setting 'user.timezone' to 'Europe/Paris'
setting 'java.awt.printerjob' to 'sun.print.PSPrinterJob'
setting 'file.encoding' to 'UTF8'
setting 'java.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'java.class.path' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar'
setting 'user.name' to 'urvoy_p'
setting 'play.version' to ' ]; then
  PLAY_VERSION='
setting 'java.vm.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'sun.java.command' to 'xsbt.boot.Boot project universail ~run'
setting 'java.home' to '/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre'
setting 'sun.arch.data.model' to '64'
setting 'user.language' to 'en'
setting 'java.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'awt.toolkit' to 'sun.awt.X11.XToolkit'
setting 'java.vm.info' to 'mixed mode'
setting 'java.version' to '1.7.0_75'
setting 'java.ext.dirs' to '/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext'
setting 'sun.boot.class.path' to '/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/resources.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/rt.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/jce.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/classes'
setting 'java.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'file.separator' to '/'
setting 'java.vendor.url.bug' to 'http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/'
setting 'sun.io.unicode.encoding' to 'UnicodeLittle'
setting 'sun.cpu.endian' to 'little'
setting 'sun.desktop' to 'gnome'
setting 'sun.cpu.isalist' to ''
setting 'ivy.default.ivy.user.dir' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository'
setting 'ivy.home' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository'
setting 'ivy.cache.dir' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache'
no default cache defined: set to /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache
setting 'ivy.checksums' to 'sha1,md5'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/boot'
setting 'basedir' to '/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/sbt/boot'
setting 'scala' to '2.9.2'
:: resolving dependencies :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0
        confs: [default]
        validate = true
        refresh = false
resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
== resolving dependencies for org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 [default]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 of rootConf=default
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0->org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}} [default->default(compile)]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}} of rootConf=default
        using redefined-public to resolve org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
redefined-public: Checking cache for: dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}} {default=[default(compile)]}
redefined-public: no namespace defined: using system
        no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
redefined-public: no latest strategy defined: using default
local: no namespace defined: using system
        no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
         trying /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
                tried /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
        local: resource not reachable for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=/home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
        local: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
Maven2 Local: no namespace defined: using system
        no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
         trying file:///home/urvoy_p/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
                tried file:///home/urvoy_p/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
        Maven2 Local: resource not reachable for org/scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=file:/home/urvoy_p/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
        Maven2 Local: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
typesafe-ivy-releases: no namespace defined: using system
        no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
         trying http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
                tried http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
HTTP response status: 404 url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/ivys/ivy.xml
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/ivys/ivy.xml
        typesafe-ivy-releases: resource not reachable for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
        typesafe-ivy-releases: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
Maven Central: no namespace defined: using system
        no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
         trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
                tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
HTTP response status: 404 url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/sbt-$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D.pom
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/sbt-$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D.pom
        Maven Central: resource not reachable for org/scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
        Maven Central: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
WARN:   module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
WARN: ==== local: tried
WARN:   /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
WARN: ==== Maven2 Local: tried
WARN:   file:///home/urvoy_p/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
WARN: ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
WARN:   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
WARN: ==== Maven Central: tried
WARN:   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
Nbr of module to sort : 0
        resolved ivy file produced in /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache/resolved-org.scala-sbt-boot-app-1.0.xml
:: downloading artifacts ::
:: resolution report :: resolve 868ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Nbr of module to sort : 0
        report for org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 default produced in /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/framework/../repository/cache/org.scala-sbt-boot-app-default.xml
        resolve done (868ms resolve - 0ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}

        ==== local: tried

          /home/urvoy_p/Programmes/play-2.1.5/repository/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== Maven2 Local: tried

          file:///home/urvoy_p/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:695)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:780)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:703)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:575)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:233)
        at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Checks.java:105)
        at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$3.call(Update.scala:99)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
        at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Checks.java:100)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:275)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.retrieve$1(Launch.scala:145)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:153)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:138)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:174)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:89)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
        at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:22)
        at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Checks.java:105)
        at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$3.call(Update.scala:99)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
        at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Checks.java:100)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:275)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.retrieve$1(Launch.scala:145)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:153)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:138)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:174)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:89)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

Comment: do you have play plugin installed in intellij

Comment: Yes I do, both play2 & scala plugins.

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896796/org-scala-sbtsbtsbt-version-not-found-on-existing-project

Comment: Yes, it reloaded all the stuff and the same error happened

Comment: How do you run the project? Is this inside IDEA or on command line? What's the steps to reproduce the issue? I'm very concerned with `"-Dplay.version= ]; then   PLAY_VERSION="` in the command line in the first snippet. How did you import it in IDEA?

Comment: Yes, this is an **IDEA command line**. The project is heavy, I imported it using sbt import. I also tried to set my play version **(Play 2.1.5)** using that command line in a terminal but it didn't change anything.