# IntelliJ - Clonning existing playframework project from bitbucket

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, bitbucket, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to clone an existing play! project from bitbucket, this repo only contains the files which aren't ignored by the default play's .gitignore file.
I get the files correctly but the problem is, how should I add the rest of the files and directories any play! application contains? I mean, how should I make it a play! applicacion as when you do a "play new" in the terminal?

I get the next directories form the repository with their files:

- app/
- public/
- conf/
- test/

I need to make this project a play! one (with its libraries and target/ project/ directories).

I tried to create the play application first, but git doens't allow me to clone a repository on my project directory because "the directory already exists".

I'm using intellij IDEA 12 with bitbucket plugin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure, **you are looking at a Play 1 application. Not a Play2 application** as you tagged. However, if I am terribly wrong and your application is indeed a Play2 here is some information on the project structure :

- **target** : The target directory contains your compiled application. When you use `play run` in that directory, the target directory will appear.
- **project** : This folder contains the Build.scala file and other configuration files.
- **lib** : If the project contains no lib folder, that means all it's dependencies are managed via the build file.

As a conclusion, just launch `play` in the project directory and you will have a running/working application.

PS : You might want to check out the official documentation on a [Play project structure.](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Anatomy)

Comment: +1, Thanks Michiel! I launched play in my project directory as you pointed and got an error saying "Unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found. This error led me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327123/error-module-not-found-org-scala-sbtsbtsbt-version) and I could get it my play app running and well generated :)